# Upload image to html

Tags: node.js, mongodb

i'm trying to upload my image and saves it automatically to my database (mongodb). But i'm stuck with uploading the image. Here's my server.js:

```
var express =   require("express");
var multer  =   require('multer');
var app         =   express();
var storage =   multer.diskStorage({
  destination: function (req, file, callback) {
    callback(null, './uploads');
  },
  filename: function (req, file, callback) {
    callback(null, file.fieldname + '-' + Date.now());
  }
});
var upload = multer({ storage : storage}).single('userPhoto');

app.get('/',function(req,res){
      res.sendFile(__dirname + "/index.html");
});

app.post('/api/photo',function(req,res){
    upload(req,res,function(err) {
        if(err) {
            return res.end("Error uploading file.");
        }
        res.end("File is uploaded");
    });
});

app.listen(3000,function(){
    console.log("Working on port 3000");
});
```

And here's my index.html:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <title>File upload Node.</title>
  </head>
  <body>
      <form id="uploadForm"
         enctype="multipart/form-data"
         action="/api/photo"
         method="post">
      <input type="file" name="userPhoto" />
      <input type="submit" value="Upload Image" name="submit">
      <span id = "status"></span>
    </form>
  </body>
  <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="http://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery.form/3.51/jquery.form.min.js"></script>
  <script src="http://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery.form/3.51/jquery.form.min.js"></script>

  <script>
  $(document).ready(function() {

         $('#uploadForm').submit(function() {
            $("#status").empty().text("File is uploading...");
            $(this).ajaxSubmit({

                error: function(xhr) {
            status('Error: ' + xhr.status);
                },

                success: function(response) {
            $("#status").empty().text(response);
                    console.log(response);
                }
        });
            //Very important line, it disable the page refresh.
        return false;
        });    
    });
  </script>

</html>
```

I got this error when i try to run it

```
POST http://localhost:8051/api/photo 404 ()
send @ jquery.min.js:4
ajax @ jquery.min.js:4
o @ jquery.form.min.js:1
e.fn.ajaxSubmit @ jquery.form.min.js:1
(anonymous function) @ (index):25
dispatch @ jquery.min.js:3
i @ jquery.min.js:3
(index):28 
Uncaught TypeError: status is not a function(…)
error @ (index):28
t.error @ jquery.form.min.js:1
n @ jquery.min.js:2
fireWith @ jquery.min.js:2
w @ jquery.min.js:4
d @ jquery.min.js:4
```

My question is, how do i fix the error and how do i save the image to mongodb?  Thankyou.

Comment: The error is quite obvious, in the browser you haven't defined a `status()` function, but you're trying to use it in your `error` handler.

Comment: Also, if you want to stream files directly to mongodb, you would need to drop down to a module like `busboy` which gives you that kind of access to file streams.

Answer (score 0):

You're getting an error on line 28:

```
            status('Error: ' + xhr.status);
```

You probably want to change that line to:

```
$("#status").empty().text('Error: ' + xhr.status);
```

That won't fix your problem, but it should show the upload error you're getting so you can take the next step.  Good luck!

Comment: it works for the upload problem, but the 404 error still exists